# Function to insert missing image size attributes into img tags

Tags: functions, images

I want to add a custom function to scan my website and automatically insert image size attributes that are missing on my pages.

For example, if there is an image on one of my pages that looks like the following:

```
<img src="https://link.to/sum/img.jpg" alt="Image Title">
```

If `img.jpg` actual size is **150x50 px**, the function would pick up on that and insert the proper `width` and `height` tags:

```
<img width="150" height="50" src="https://link.to/sum/img.jpg" alt="Image Title">
```

Comment: Will they all be images from the WordPress media library?

Comment: Yes, they will be from the Media library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function replaceImageMeta( $imagename ) {

    preg_match_all('/(alt|title|src)=("[^"]*")/i',$imagename, $img);//var_dump( str_replace("\"", "" , ( $img[2][0] ) ) );

    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( str_replace("\"", "" , ( $img[2][0] ) ));

    $imgname = str_replace("\"", "" , ( $img[2][0] ) );

    return sprintf('<img src="%s" width="%dpx" height="%dpx" >', str_replace("\"", "" , ( $img[2][0] ) ), $width, $height);

}
```

So call the function with image string

```
replaceImageMeta( "<img src=\"https://link.to/sum/img.jpg\" alt=\"Image Title\" >" )
```